# can not login into sqldeveloper

Tags: java, database, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I just got started with Oracle in Linux , so I don't know anything about it.
i have installed **oracle-xe-11.2.0-1.0.x86_64** from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/566734/how-to-install-oracle-11gr2-on-ubuntu-14-04)
and after that I have logon to sqlplus 
via this command : `sqlplus sys as sysdba`
after that I created an user and grant access to it via `grant connect, resource to MYUSER;`

everything works fine and now i can enter to sql plus via my username and password but in the sqldeveloper 
when i want to create a connection it returns me some errors
:

```
Status : Failure -Test failed: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor
```

But I enter the information correctly!

```
hostname : localhost or 127.0.0.1

port : 1521 

sid : xe or db
```

testing both of them
at last , not working 
[sqldeveloper form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6MD98.png)

Comment: What happens if you use the radio buttons to change to the service name (rather than SID) and supply XE for *that*?

Comment: i dont understand your answer

Comment: i complete sqldeveloper add connection form , where i user radio button ?

Comment: try the bequeath connection type...and also, ping the listener, see what databases IT IS listening for. Run this at CMD prompt 'lsnrctl status'. You should see an entry for XE

Comment: i entered your command. it gives me lots of information . which field do you want ?

Comment: my connection type is basic and my role is default

Comment: @thatjeffsmith Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
Start Date                21-JUN-2018 18:18:49
Uptime                    0 days 1 hr. 18 min. 19 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Default Service           XE
Listener Parameter File   /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/network/admin/listener.ora
Listener Log File         /u01/app/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/mahdiyar-laptop/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...

Comment: DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=EXTPROC_FOR_XE)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=mahdiyar-laptop.test.com)(PORT=1521)))
Services Summary...
Service "PLSExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "PLSExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully

Comment: @SeyyedMahdiyarZerehpoush - [in the connection settings panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OCQza.png). Please edit your question to add the listener information, don't add that kind of information as comments, it's really hard to read. Sounds like you might have [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21553557/266304) too though.

Comment: @AlexPoole i clicked in service name and entered "XE" but problem not solved

Comment: No, because of the other issue I linked to (the error should have changed to refer to service name instead of SID now). As it's local, try Jeff's suggestion of switching to a Local/Bequeath connection, from the 'connection type' drop-down on that dialog.

Comment: @AlexPoole i tested  suggestion. new error is this : Status : Failure -Test failed: no ocijdbc12 in java.library.path

Comment: from your comments it looks like the listener isn't configured correctly, it's not setup for XE - see the link that @AlexPoole left for you

Comment: It sounds like `mahdiyar-laptop.test.com` is resolving to the same as `localhost`, 127.0.0.1; but your DB is trying to register using your LAN IP address. The DB and listener need to be using the same address, or names that resolve to the same address. Whether you want to consolidate on localhost, which means no-one else can reach your DB, or your external IP (beware of DHCP though) is up to you. [The listener can even listen for both if you want](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35746373/266304).

Answer (score 1):

you could update host name (computer name) in `tnsnames.ora` and `listener.ora` file in oracle directory .  save it and  retry .

Answer (score 0):

Here are some possible reasons for this exception:

1) The name of the database XE by default. The url should be like:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE
```

or

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/XE
```

2) Make sure that OracleServiceXE, OracleXETNSListener is running. Check in:

```
Control_Panel\All_Control_Panel_Items\Administrative_Tools\Services
```

Open Services, and start OracleServiceXE, after that try to connect...

Comment: i use ubuntu :D

Comment: service is up because i can login via this username and password in sqlplus

Comment: Ajam... let me check a litle bit more @SeyyedMahdiyarZerehpoush

Comment: One possibility is that there may be a problem resolving the hostname on the host machine itself. If there is no entry for $(hostname) in /etc/hosts, the Oracle listener gets confused and wont come up.
Check in /etc/hosts file if there are the hostname and ip address.

Comment: The listener is generating the ORA-12505, so it is up. The DB isn't registered with it though - which could be because it can't resolve localhost as you suggest, or because it's trying to register against the LAN IP address instead.

Comment: out put : 127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.1.1 mahdiyar-ubuntu

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters